# Unity Free Inverse Depth Mask?

Tags: unity, shaders, depth-buffer, masking

How would it be possible to create an inverse depth mask? In this case, I refer to a depth mask as a shader attached to a mesh that 'pokes a hole' through the current camera layer to let you see the camera render layer one depth down, usually by using ColorMask 0.

What I want is for, instead, the mesh to determine what ISN'T cut out, without everything that is NOT seen through the mesh being cut out.